# Async await in node js with readline inside for loop

Tags: node.js, for-loop, stream, async-await

So I'm unable to force a for loop to wait for the stream to close before performing the next iteration.

It seems streaming data and async/await don't seem to get along (especially in for loops). Possibly one way around it may be to put everything in an infinite while loop (instead of a for loop) and use a POSIX mutex type method (where a flag is set, blocking opening a stream until the flag is reset at when the stream closes, and counters update). But there must be some kind of way to accomplish it with async/await.

Below is some test code:

```
async function bulk_search(an_array)
{    
    var name = "";
    var found = false;

    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for(let j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            for(let k = 0; k < 10; k++)
            {
                console.log(i + ", " + j + ", " + k);
                file_stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/a_directory/a_file.csv');

                file_stream.on('error', function (err) {
                    return an_array;
                });

                csv_file = readline.createInterface({
                    input: file_stream
                });

                name = an_array[i][j][k];
                found = false;

                csv_file.on('line', function (line) {                   
                    if(name == line)
                    {
                        found = true;
                        csv_file.close();
                    }
                });

                await csv_file.on('close', function() {
                    console.log("Closing Stream");
                    if(found == false)
                    {
                        an_array[i][j][k] = "";
                    }
                    if((i == 9) && (j == 9) && (k == 9))
                    {
                        return an_array;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `await` expects a promise. `csv_file.on` doesn't return a promise.

Comment: Move the guts of your loop into a `Promise` and resolve on `close`, then you can `await` it